# How do I change the color of the checkbox?

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox, styles

Ok so I made a show hide toggle checkbox for a password input. However, I cannot figure out how to get the "when checked" background of the checkbox to be a different color.

In our existing code base there is a custom checkbox that uses custom styling, however I cannot use this checkbox for this feature as it does not use ng-model.

[image]

```html
<input style="color: #009688;" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the standard way, you cannot set the background color for `checkbox` without using plugins or custom modifications. But there is one trick that will allow you to give the background color. Use rule `filter` with parameter `hue-rotate()`.

Also, it is possible to get the value `deg` by converting the `RGB` code.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(1):checked {
    filter: hue-rotate(240deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(2):checked {
    filter: hue-rotate(285deg);
}


input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(3):checked {
    filter: hue-rotate(300deg);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(4):checked {
    filter: hue-rotate(320deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"> <!--ORIGINAL-->
```